# How to interpret the wave function for non point-like objects

Tags: quantum-mechanics

The accepted interpretation of a single-particle wave function is that it represents (among other things) the probability of finding the particle at any point. The wave function is normalised so that the probability sums to 1 over space.

In principle, how might the accepted interpretation address the hypothetical case of a non-point-like object with no component parts?

For those of you who might not see the point of the question, consider the 2D 'particle in a box' scenario, in which a point particle is constrained to lie on some portion of the X-axis by a pair of potential barriers. Now replace the point particle by a square particle the length of whose sides is greater than half the width of the box. The particle can move, but there are now values of x for which the particle will always be found, so it is no longer possible to normalise the wave function, and it is no longer possible to associate the particle unambiguously with a given value of x.

Comment: Consider the two sentences "there are now values of x for which the particle will always be found" and "it is no longer possible to associate the particle unambiguously with a given value of x" in your question. The first sentence implies that the square particle's position is not well defined to begin with, because you are saying that irrespective of the position of e.g. the centre of the particle, you *also* associate e.g. the middle of the potential well with the "position" of the particle.

Comment: But if this is the case, how can you expect to identify "the particle unambiguously with a given value of x"? tl;dr: Please define exactly what you mean by "the position of the square particle" in this hypothetical scenario.

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer That is exactly my point. The position can only be defined by reference to a range of values of x, which is at odds with the usual interpretation of the wavefunction.

Comment: But I dont see what this has to do with QM. You cannot assign a unique position to an extended body classically either? How do you set up thr classical equations of motion for an extended square particle?

Comment: Another aspect of this is that there are many things in QM that dont have (spatial) wave functions. Spin comes to mind.

Comment: In classical mechanics I can specify the position of a square body straightforwardly, for example by providing the coordinates of a pair of opposite corners. Classical mechanics has no problem with that. Quantum mechanics does, however, since it assumes the eigenfunction of position are delta functions of zero spatial extent.

Comment: Assuming the square particle is rigid and of length r, confined in an infinite well that streches from x=0 to x=L, then surely a measurement of the position of the left corner will yeild a value of x between 0 and L-r. Also rigidity means that the left corner "experiences" an infinite potential when x < 0 or x > L-r. What prevents me from writing down a wave function for the left corner in the standard way? Measuring the position of it collapes the wave function onto a delta function. So what?

Comment: Or if we are more comfortable with the centre of mass, it is confined to r/2 < x < L-r/2 and a measurement of "the position of the particle" is a measurement for the centre of mass, which is a point!

Comment: Sorry, not trying to be annoying, just trying to see where my naive constructions fails. I just dont expect extended objects to have delta functions as eigenfunctions to position. We're not measuring the position of a *point*, after all.

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer. You are certainly not annoying! Your suggestions are both helpful and ingenious. However, my feeling is that there is a structural quality to QM that makes it intrinsically suited to the treatment of point particles in a way that classical mechanics is not. My question was designed to probe whether this was an issue that had been considered earlier- I suspect it has not been. All the best.

Answer (score 0):

The wave function will necessarily include all degrees of freedom the particle has: position, orientation, deformations, etc.

Comment: This doesn't address the question.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, you cannot talk about a wave function for a non point particle. A non point particle is a body, composed of many particles, and you have to write down the wave function for the coordinates of each particle composing the body. Of course, as in classical mechanics, you can make approximation, like idealizing the body as rigid. This means that you can write the wave function as a function of the center of mass coordinate, and the coordinates of the other particles are fixed once the center of mass coordinate has been chosen, but this is just an approximation.

Comment: I think you missed my point. I said in my question that the non-point-like object has no component parts, so it is not composed of many particles

Comment: I think you missed Damiano's point "you cannot talk about a wave function for a non point particle"

Comment: @JamesK. Indeed, that's the heart of the question. It seems to me that an implicit but rarely mentioned assumption inherent in QM is that wave functions apply to  point particles or collections of them which may be spatially spread, but cannot apply to non-pointlike particles. Having let the community stew on this question, I propose to ask another relating to the implications of real particles having finite spatial extents.